# i keep getting this error "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

Tags: reactjs

```
    TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
      ClassCard
      C:/Users/hp/Desktop/abe2021/src/components/ClassList/ClassCard.js:8
         5 | 
         6 | const ClassCard = ({Names}) => {
         7 | 
      >  8 |    const cardComp = Names.map((Names, i) => {
           | ^   9 |        return <ClassList 
        10 |        key={i} 
        11 |        id={Names[i].id}
```

i am trying to map through an arrary in my react project and i keep getting  the error above

Comment: Can you include please how you are using `<ClassCard />` component? Maybe not passing `Names` props down.

Comment: `Names` is surely undefined.. Check what you actually pass to the `ClassCard` component as the Names argument

Comment: `Names` is  `undefined`

Comment: Also, the way you are hiding `Names` in the closure using another `Names` is really strange. It seems there will be another crash on `Names[i].id`.

Answer (score 1):

## Names is undefined (or just not an array)

You cannot `map` over `undefined` or `null` since map is an array method.

Assign a default empty array value

```
const ClassCard = ({Names = []}) => {
  const cardComp = Names.map((Names, i) => {
  ...
  }
}
```

or check if your Names array exists

```
const ClassCard = ({Names}) => {
  const cardComp = Names && Names.map((Names, i) => {
  ...
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, that's ez to fix, maybe in another components you have edited Names in a way that doesn't make it an array anymore, that's why you can't use the method `.map` with it, try to check if the type of Names is `array` or not.
Maybe you should also provide us with more code so we can see where exactly the mistake is.

Thanks :)